# Angular Date time Spring boot LocalDateTime have wrong time, minus 5 hours and 30 minutes

Tags: spring-boot, time, calendar, primeng, localdatetime

I am using primeng calendar in my angular application where the backend is java spring boot.
In java date is coming correctly where the **time is wrong**

```
 <p-calendar formControlName="screeningDate" [maxDate]="today" dateFormat="dd/mm/yy"
                                        [showTime]="true" [hourFormat]="12" showButtonBar="true"></p-calendar>
```

and Java field

```
private LocalDateTime screeningDate;
```

where in page I have selected 05:48 PM but at restController  `@RequestBody`
receving 12:18 (2022-01-10T12:18:09.318)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using a ZonedDateTime if your angular application is sending it with the timezone to the backend. LocalDateTime will instantiate the date at the timezone configured in the JVM or the OS if not explicit.

Comment: Hi, I tried ZonedDateTime, but same issue